# Pandas Concat is running into Memory Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to pre process data for further analysis. First I'm reading the data from a csv file ( x ).

Then I am splitting it up into three parts. Lastly I need to transform one array using `get_dummies`, `concat` and `sum` for the result of `groupby`.

```
import pandas as pd

RawData_v2_clear=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\top200users_filtered.csv', 
        sep=';', usecols = ['Username', 'Code', 'Object'], error_bad_lines=False, 
        encoding='latin-1')

dfU = RawData_v2_clear['Username']              
dfT = RawData_v2_clear['Code']   
dfO = RawData_v2_clear['Object'] 

del RawData_v2_clear, dfO                               (to free up some memory)

df_newT = pd.concat([dfU,pd.get_dummies(dfT)],axis=1)

df_new_gbyT = df_newT.groupby('Username').sum()
```

`Raw_Data_V2_clear` has shape (~11 million rows x 3 columns).

```
Error:
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Faulty_Skript.py", line XXX, in <module>
    df_newT = pd.concat([dfU,pd.get_dummies(dfT)],axis=1).sum()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 866, in get_dummies
    dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 963, in _get_dummies_1d
    dummy_mat = np.eye(number_of_cols, dtype=dtype).take(codes, axis=0)
MemoryError
```

On another system this operations takes some time but finished without `Memory Error`. Maybe someone has a good idea to fix this memory issue? Maybe append is more memory friendly than concat? However my implementation of append failed as well on my current system.

Thank you very much!

Comment: A more general solution would be using Dask instead. I ran into this issue very often while dealing with large datasets. If you're using ipython/jupyter notebook, maybe try resetting kernel to free memory. Also maybe try reading csv in chunks and then concatenating them later?

Comment: Maybe try casting 'Username' column to `category` dtype..? Could try passing `dtype={'Username': 'category'}` to read_csv method...?

Comment: @YashNag Yeah I tried Spyder and VS Code via Conda. However both ran into the same issue. It's hard to concatenate them later, because this is my final data I will analyse. It's confusing, that this is running just fine on another less powerful system. 

Chris: I have 3000 different usernames, so using it as category might not help that much right?

Comment: category type is super memory efficient. If it's type 'object' just now, casting to category will free up a lot of space... encodes as 'int' under-the-hood. Worth a try anyway if you have over 11M rows with only 3000 unique usernames...  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categorical-memory

Comment: @ChrisA I tried your previous answer, but I'm stil running into ```Memory Error```

Comment: @Mike_H sorry to hear that buddy. It looks like your ultimately trying to create the cross-tab of 'Usernames' and 'codes'...? Try reading in, with `dtype='category'` and then go straight to `df_new_gbyT = pd.crosstab(RawData_v2_clear.Username, RawData_v2_clear.Code)` ..?

Comment: MVP  please post it as the answer :D despite I'm not sure if the result is correct. But time will tell!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try [`dtype='category'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) parameter in `read_csv` method and [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) instead:

```
import pandas as pd

RawData_v2_clear=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\top200users_filtered.csv', 
        sep=';', usecols = ['Username', 'Code', 'Object'], error_bad_lines=False, 
        encoding='latin-1', dtype='category')

df_new_gbyT = pd.crosstab(RawData_v2_clear.Username, RawData_v2_clear.Code)
```